# ¿Cómo enviar una notificación al recibir una alerta, usando PHP|MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

Mediante arduino, obtengo información de temperatura, humedad entre otros sensores, toda esta información la estoy registrando sin problemas en la base de datos MYSQL.

Pero necesito poder notificar por correo electrónico y, quizás a futuro por SMS cuando exista alguna anomalía, algo que este anormal entre los sensores.

He registrado de manera manual, un valor anormal de temperatura, por ejemplo:

```
if ($temperature === "900") {
   mail('@', 'Notificación', 'prueba...');
}
```

Pensando que el archivo automáticamente me enviaría el mensaje, pero no, tengo que abrir el archivo `avise.php` para que se ejecute el envío de ese mensaje.

Cómo puedo hacer que este archivo `avise.php` se ejecute cada 60 segundos automáticamente sin que tenga que ingresar a dicho archivo, así poder recibir las notificaciones cuando existe alguna anomalía.

Comment: Podrías programar un cron o una tarea que ejecute tu script PHP cada X tiempo. Revisa por ejemplo [este post](https://descubrearduino.com/como-programar-una-tarea-en-una-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: @A.Cedano El `CRON` lo podría mencionar a los expertos en `arduino`, para que lo tengan presente, ya en la segunda opción como se emplea una tarea para que se ejecute el script PHP, es con esto `set_time_limit(60);` buscando referencia eso mencionan aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726116/run-a-php-script-every-second-using-cli

Comment: @A.Cedano No logro comprenderlo, https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: @A.Cedano Probé lo siguiente `header('refresh:10; url=same_page.php');` pero solo funciona cuando esta abierto el archivo :/

Comment: @A.Cedano Obligatoriamente me toca utilizar `Cronjob` pero no sé como emplear `CRON` en el hosting GoDaddy, usa CPANEL.

Comment: @A.Cedano No observo que lo pueda configurar cada 30 segundos https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/82Docs/Cron+Jobs

Comment: El problema, creo yo, es que estás confundiendo conceptos. Por un lado necesitas tu Script PHP sin más, en él no tienes que preocuparte porque se lance cada X tiempo con encabezados u otras historias. Para que se lance cada X tiempo tienes que programar un Cron **que llame a tu Script PHP** indicando **en el cron** la frecuencia que quieres y la ruta del Script. Como llamas un Script de PHP puedes llamar otro Script, si quieres controlar la temperatura desde otro código (un archivo .ssh por ejemplo).

Comment: Yo los tiempos menores de un minuto prefiero controlarlos desde php, las tareas cron de linux no gestionan segundos. Pero si necesitas, aunque sea para probar, un cron cada 30 segundos puedes hacer dos idénticos y a uno de ellos le pones primero `sleep 30 &&` y después lo que necesites para lanzar el script. Esto lo que hará será esperar 30 segundos antes de ejecutar el script y así ya se ejecuta 30 segundos después del primero. Puedes usar tiempos menores añadiendo mas tareas cron idénticas con pausas menores.

Comment: @Fly No le entiendo al fondo sobre el tema de CRON, lo que si es que el hosting es de linux. /:

Comment: Las tareas cron son un tema de sistemas, no de programación. Según lo que pretendas realizar podrías prescindir de ellas si no te interesa investigar su funcionamiento, basta con que envíes la notificación desde el mismo script que se encarga de imputar en base de datos. No necesitas un cron cada 30 segundos, solo cada vez que exista una lectura. Lo malo de esto es que no podrías enviar una notificación en caso de no recibir lecturas, por ejemplo.

Comment: @Fly Gracias por la información, muy concreto, ahora podré seguir con la marcha del proyecto.

Comment: que yo sepa todos los hosting deben tener cron porque solo es una tarea programada cualquier servidor lo puede hacer

Comment: ¿Cómo es la comunicación entre arduino y el host con php?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes enviar la notificación justo antes de hacer el registro en la base de datos, de esta manera no necesitas funciones externas.

Te dejo una idea de como lo puedes lograr...

Al recibir los datos, comparas el valor recibido con un valor estándar, por ejemplo:

```
if ($_GET['temperature'] >= 300) {
    mail('@', 'Notificación', 'prueba...');
}
insert into...
```

Modifica el ejemplo para adaptarlo a tu proyecto, cambiando el método con el que recibes los datos, por ejemplo, o si usas librerías para el envío de email como `phpMailer`. Si tienes dudas adicionales, deja tu comentario.